# module 'tensorflow.python.keras.utils.generic_utils' has no attribute 'populate_dict_with_module_objects'

Tags: python, tensorflow

When trying to import tensorflow I keep on getting this error. I have tried reinstalling tensorflow but I still revive this problem on this statement:

import tensorflow as tf

Does anyone have advice? Tensorflow worked on my system before I originally reinstalled it but now I have no luck. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain more about your environment? OS? Version of your language? This will help us to reproduce the error or see similar situations.

Comment: I am using this on python 3.8, and I downloaded tensorflow through pip. I can compile my file properly by using anaconda but I was wondering why it didn't work using pip.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up deleting my python and re downloading it